# Bulk pdf generation with puppeteer and adm-zip, showing error node:internal/crypto/hash:113 if (!this[kHandle].update(data, encoding))

Tags: node.js

I'm generating pdf in bulk with puppeteer and adm-zip but when it goes to insert the generated pdfs in the zip file, it returns the error

This is my code.

`router.get('/:database/:tipo/:ids/:limite?.zip', async (req, res) => {
const { database, tipo, ids, limite } = req.params;

```
let idsArray;
if (ids === "ids") {
  const pool = new Pool({
    user: process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
    host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST,
    database: database,
    password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
    port: process.env.POSTGRES_PORT,
  });

  let query = `SELECT id FROM controle_interno.${tipo} ORDER BY id ASC`;
  if (limite) {
    query += ` LIMIT ${limite}`;
  }
  const result = await pool.query(query);
  idsArray = result.rows.map(row => row.id);
} else {
  idsArray = ids.split(",");
}

const zip = new AdmZip();
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  args: ['--disable-gpu', '--disable-software-rasterizer', '--disable-dev-shm-usage', '--disable-setuid-sandbox', '--no-sandbox']
});
const page = await browser.newPage();

for (let i = 0; i < idsArray.length; i++) {
  const id = idsArray[i];
  const url = `http://${IP}:${port}/${database}/${tipo}/${id}`;
  console.log(url);
  try {
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});
  await page.evaluate(() => {
    const button = document.getElementById('gerar-pdf');
    button.remove();
  });
const pdf = await page.pdf({ format: 'A4', printBackground: true, pageRanges: '1' });
  zip.addFile(`${id}.pdf`, pdf, `PDF para o ID ${id}`);
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err.stack);
 }
}

await browser.close();
const zipBuffer = zip.toBuffer();

res.set({
  'Content-Type': 'application/zip',
  'Content-Disposition': `attachment; filename=${tipo}.zip`,
  'Content-Length': zipBuffer.length
});

res.send(zipBuffer);
```

});

module.exports = router;`

I'm pulling data from a view and inserting the ejs file, I've tried with other views and it doesn't return this error, only with a specific view, maybe it could be the view's data? It doesn't return any error when I generate each one individually, only when it's in bulk.

I haven't tried any alternative yet, I just thought I'd review the view and change the data, but there's no incorrect data that can be corrected in my view...

Answer (score 0):

I found the error, some pdfs generated by puppeteer had very high image resolution, causing the pdf to be between 10 and 30mb in size, I did a test generating only 200 and it returned 1.1gb of data. I changed the resolution of the images and did the mass generation again, I managed to generate them all and the zipped file size was 787mb.